# Is it possible to open a page and click a button on another page using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to load a page on the same site and click a link. I can either use php or javascript. Is this possible.

Comment: load a page... yes but click a link...no If this was possible there would be loads of spammers

Answer (score 1):

One way i am getting to mind now is to send a paramater in the URL.
And the do a `$_GET`.If it is set to a particular value then  do a 
`<script> document.getElementById("id").click();  </script>`